# Mount and Access files in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, fstab

I have 2 disks: an ssd to boot the OS and a 1TB HDD with my old files from windows. In the installation I didn't even mess with that, just formatted the SSD and installed ubuntu.

The disk automounts at boot, I can access the files and see what's in them but I cannot delete or write to the disk for some reason.

Here is my /etc/fstab file contents:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=5c5fce50-df37-4940-aad3-f7879bc727e7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=EBB2-0261  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=E8DCB0ECDCB0B662 /data    auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

And here is the sudo blkid:

```
/dev/sda2: UUID="5c5fce50-df37-4940-aad3-f7879bc727e7" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="cb08ef2c-8daf-4bc7-8fdc-6ed65a324965"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="EBB2-0261" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="b60113e0-acf9-49c4-bf55-fafb3bd27fce"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="DATA" UUID="E8DCB0ECDCB0B662" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="47caf097-c6a7-4d4f-a9e6-0942c9ac8483"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
```

As you can see I went to the file manager and changed the name of the disk to "DATA" so I could quickly identify it, and added an entry to fstab according to some tutorials, I even ran `sudo chmod (my user):(my group) /data` but that didn't allow me to delete files and create them and when the PC rebooted the ownership of the disk went back to root (i checked it via file manager > properties > Permissions).

Can anyone help me automount this disk and get access to delete and create files on it?

EDIT: I am in a big hurry so I went to Ubuntu's Disk manager, backed up my data (only 60gigs or so) and deleted that big partition an created a new one (also formated the disk).

Comment: If your Windows had "Fast Boot" enabled when it last shutdown, Windows left the disk in a weird, undocumented state. Linux doesn't understand fastbootified disks, but it looks like NTFS, so, read-only access allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu by default just reads NTFS. To enable writing to NTFS you need to have a package installed, if it is not installed, install.it like this:

sudo apt install ntfs-3g

Then unmount partition, and mount it properly with read-write permissions.

P.S. Setting Linux style permissions on NTFS file system does not work, unless there's some kind of translation layer between them, and it certainly won't set permissions if file system is read-only.